# How to add more text with forEach inside a string?

Tags: javascript, xml, string, foreach

So, I dont know if this is possible in JS, what I want to do it's something like this:

I have N objects, and want to formulate a XML with them

```
import config from './config'; //that actually doesent matter
//just show it here because the xml that I return have a LOT of data
//from this config

buildXML(objects) => {
 return `
   <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>
   <my-xml>
     <id>${config.id}</id>
     ${objects.forEach(object) => {
       return '<object>' + object + '</object>'
     }}
   </my-xml>
 `
}
```

I wanted the result to me something like

```
  <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>
   <my-xml>
     <id>42</id>
     <object> OBJECT </object>
     <object> OBJECT </object>
   </my-xml>
```

There's a way I can do it? Any help is welcome :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance:

```
return `
   <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>
   <my-xml>
     <id>${config.id}</id>
     ${objects.map(object => {
       return '<object>' + object + '</object>'
     }).join('')}
   </my-xml>`;
```

or even shorter:

```
return `
   <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>
   <my-xml>
     <id>${config.id}</id>
     ${objects.map(object => `<object>${object}</object>`).join('')}
   </my-xml>`;
```

Comment: Dont know i have to use .join('')... Thanks idmean!